# Password protecting a sef url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, authorization, password-protection

I have a web site `http://www.example.com`

Also a virtual directory or URL `http://www.example.com/admin/`

Please note, there isn't an actual directory called `/admin`

How do I password protect this `http://www.example.com/admin/` URL with `.htaccess`?

I've tried these methods:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /adminpanel/%1 [PT]

<LocationMatch "/adminpanel/">
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "By Invitation Only"
     AuthUserFile /home/example/public_html/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Its locking down the whole website

Also this method is not success either:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/adminpanel" SECURED

# invoke basic auth is SECURED is set
#Deny from env=SECURED
AuthType Basic
#Require valid-user
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/example/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
#Satisfy    any
Order      allow,deny
Deny from env=SECURED
Allow from  all
Satisfy    any
```

Comment: Can you post what have you attempted so far? Alternatively you could use www.google.com...

Comment: Alternatively you can also search stackoverflow.com for an easy hit

Comment: @arco444 I've just edited the post. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the rewrite rule - you're redirecting everything to `/adminpanel` in that instance. You should only need to add the following:

```
<Location "/adminpanel">
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "By Invitation Only"
     AuthUserFile /home/example/public_html/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: I tried this method. Unfortunately I'm having a 500 server error.